# Connection reset while executing multiple queries using Postgres pg and node

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Here is my code that performs multiple select queries one after other.

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');    
const pool   = new Pool(POSTGRES_CONFIG);

var aggregateDomainCount = [], domainCount={};

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Connection error', err.stack)
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
    client.query(firstQuery, function(err, results) {
          // call `done()` to release the client back to the pool      
          if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
          }
          domainCount = {"data1":results.rows[0].count};
          aggregateDomainCount.push(domainCount);
     });
     ......

     client.query(lastQuery, function(err, results) {
          // call `done()` to release the client back to the pool      
          if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
          }
          domainCount = {"dataN":results.rows[0].count};
          aggregateDomainCount.push(domainCount);
          release();
          response.json(aggregateDomainCount);
     });
});
```

The issue is while executing above queries, console first prints('Connection established') and then after series of execution, again it tries to enter pool.connect before completing all queries and prints('Connection established') and finally results in unknown error to user interface. If i reduce number of queries by some, then I get expected results but which is again inconsistent.
So far, I have tried

1. nesting client.query one inside other
2. nesting pool.connect by grouping set of queries
3. setting different timeout parameters
4. using await client.query()

But all the above resulted in same issue. Could you please point me in right direction.

Comment: That is all it says, "unknown error"?  Your title gives a seemingly more specific error message.

Comment: @jjanes - yes there is no error thrown or caught at node level but when response parsed at UI(angular), the error doesn't seem to have detailed reason.

Comment: @jjanes - I'm just guessing client connection from pool getting refreshed since it's entering pool.connect second time before completing all queries in first iteration, hence put the title accordingly. Sorry if title misled you..

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file for the real error message.  But really, why use a client which won't produce meaningful errors?